# pyqt5 get colors from system theme

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a loading bar that looks like QProgressbar

[image]

that small green rounded rectangle will move back and forth and act as a loading bar
But the issue i'm facing is that i do not know how to get the colors of that progressed part of the progressed bar. im using `QPalette().color(QPalette().Active,QPalette().Highlight` as the color for the progressed part but it looks different than the one used in QProgressBar.

The one in the right is the color i'm trying to achieve as it is using QProgressBar but on the left is what i have achieved now.
[image]
I have tried all color groups but none of them look like the qprogressBar.
I did also try switching theme and the color always differs from the QProgressBar

So how do i get the color of the QProgressBar's progressed part (green part)

I'm running manjaro kde

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QFont,QPalette,QPolygonF,QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt , QPointF,QRectF


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.position=20

    def initUI(self):


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Drawing text')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        
        width = self.width()
        height = self.height()
        
        self.widget_height= 6
        
        
        #the part of the loading bar that is not going to have the progressed part
        reduce_amount = width/3
        
        top_left =QPointF(int(width/4),int(height/2-self.widget_height/2))
        bottom_right =QPointF(int(3*width/4)-reduce_amount ,int(height/2 +self.widget_height/2))
        
        bigger_bottom_right =QPointF(int(3*width/4) ,int(height/2+self.widget_height/2) )
        
        
        recty =QRectF(QPointF(top_left.x()+self.position,top_left.y()),bottom_right)
        bigger_recty=QRectF(top_left,bigger_bottom_right)
        
        
        #non progressed part (bigger rounded rect)
        qp.setPen(QPalette().color(QPalette.Disabled,QPalette.Text))
        qp.setBrush(QBrush(QPalette().color(QPalette.Active,QPalette.Button)))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(bigger_recty,3,3)        
        
        
        #progressed part
        qp.setBrush(QBrush(QPalette().color(QPalette().Inactive,QPalette().Highlight)))
        qp.setPen(QPalette().color(QPalette().Active,QPalette().Highlight))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(recty,2,2)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You will probably *never* get the exact colors: the palette is used as reference, its colors are almost always slightly changed by the underlying *style* that actually draws the control. For instance, buttons have some "glow" effect with some styles, that is based on the `Button` role. Other styles actually use different roles for different purposes. The question here is: do you want to draw a *custom* progress bar, or do you want to actually paint a progress bar *exactly like* QProgressBar would do? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Besides, note that your computation is more complex than it should be, and you should also **not** use the event's `rect()` as a reference for the whole painting: [`rect()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html#rect) "Returns the rectangle that needs to be updated.", meaning that the rectangle might correspond to a specific area of the widget (this is done for performance, as sometimes you need to only update a portion of the widget area). If you need the widget rectangle as painting reference, use `self.rect()` or `self.width()`/`self.height()`.

Comment: @musicamante so are you me telling me that i cannot possibly create the custom progressBar that is painted exactly like QProgressBar?

Comment: @ThenujanSandramohan Exactly, native theme colors are handled by the system API and the Qt palette is only used when the element can be configured in the API. Native styles are difficult to customize because they don't depend on Qt, instead if you want to customize everything use the "fusion" style that is fully maintained by Qt.

Comment: @ThenujanSandramohan well, that depends. While there are occurrences for which it's required to *paint* a progress bar that is exactly like the "native" one (specifically, a delegate of an item view, like QTableView), most of the times that's unnecessary: why not use an *actual* QProgressBar instead? If you, instead, want to draw a completely customized progress bar (for instance, a different shape) that uses the native colors, that's different, and, as stated in the comments above: you simply can't. So, you either use an actual QProgressBar, or you decide to use something *similar* to it.

Comment: @ThenujanSandramohan what is important to understand is that QPalette is an *actual* [palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_(painting)), its name specifically means its usage: you have some basic colors, how they are actually used is up to you (or, in this case, it is up to the current style). For instance, the `Button` color role may be green, but the style might choose to draw the button with some "glow" effect to give it a 3D aspect. The palette will still give you a plain green color, but the button will be drawn in a very different way, and the palette will never give you that.

Comment: @musicamante can you write this as an answer as this question cannot possibly get any better answer.